# Making a shareable hash link javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

Okay, so I'm trying to make a shareable hash link with javascript/jQuery only (as in no server side). Is this even possible? I can successfully create the hash, but I can't get the data to populate on a different browser.

Here's my site, sorry for no code, let me know if there's something specific you'd like to see. [site](http://ugly.site44.com/rankr)

Before it gets brought up, I don't want to use the History API as of yet.

Comment: It's possible so long as you're not generating some kind of random link, and the page can just rebuild the same view each time according to the url. That's just normal routing, though. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess i'm having trouble regenerating the page. It will show the full url hash but the lists & list are not populating.

Comment: What is your basis for generating the hash? What does the hash mean?

Comment: You know I'm using local storage to maintain the lists. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: the hash is tied to the name of the list (left hand). Right side corresponds with the left side. I want to be able to share the lists that are made. Does that answer you?

Comment: Yes. localstorage is local. It has nothing to do with any other computer. You need to understand url routing and make your urls meaningful so that they page can examine them and rebuild itself consistently. It sounds like you're generating some kind of meaningless url that won't tell you what to do when it is visited.

Comment: you're right. could you point me to some resource?

Comment: I like this: https://github.com/TehShrike/abstract-state-router

Comment: ok, i appreciate you taking time for some n00bness

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72495/discussion-between-m59-and-lucusp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've determined a solution: [gistlink.js](https://github.com/lucusp/gist-permalink).

It's a little lib that *I wrote* that uses anonymous github gists to persist data.

Just thought I'd share in case someone needs a no backend solution as I did.